# What type of B&W film did Saul Leiter use?

Tags: film, black-and-white, history

As shown in Saul's monographs ***Early Black and White*** or ***In My Room***.

What kind of BW negative rolls did he use?

Comment: General note to those Googling these images - they may be NSF your W (at least, the related images may not be)

Comment: Likely Tri-X, but not today's Tri-X.  But it could have been any of several other Kodak or other films, none of which are now available.  And it really matters only a tiny bit: why obsess over film when there are also hundreds of processing options, at least tens of printing papers and hundreds of options for processing the paper?  It was just film: the start of the process.

Comment: @tfb Please see: [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871)

Comment: @MichaelC it wasn't intended as an answer: I have no idea what film he used, but am just guessing since Tri-X was/is common, & then trying to point out that the question is really meaningless.  Sorry, I should have made that more clear: do you want me to add an answer saying that more explicitly?  I think that would be a bad answer but I'm willing to be wrong!